# get html 5 date input field and pass to .net controller

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

On my razor page, I have a simple date picker that looks like this:

```
<input type="date" name="lessonsStart">
```

How would I go about getting the value of that and sending it to my controller?

Whenever I send data to my controller from a razor page, the format always looks something like this:

```
<a asp-action="LessonIndex" asp-route-id="@item.Id">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</a>
```

which sends an "item.Id" to my controller called LessonIndex().

So I'm not sure how I'd get the date value and send it.

The controller looks like this:

```
public IActionResult LessonIndex(datetime startDate) {

    var response = getLessons(startDate);

      return response.Results;
   }
```

Is there a specific format I need to use?

Note that the date is not used in a model, it just needs to be sent to a controller.

Thanks!

Comment: does 'lessonStart' correspond to a valid name in your razorpage or controller? Since you listed mvc as one of your targeted tags.

Comment: I have an idea of what you are trying to do but I need some clarification and some more source if you can provide what your controller looks like.  Also do you have a model associated with the page in question?

Comment: @mvermef lessonStart was just the name I gave the html element. It doesn’t mean anything beyond that.

Comment: this is a RazorPage or Mvc Controller that you want this to get back to? 2 ways to acheive 1) javascript or 2) post a form.

Comment: @mvermef I also added the method in the controller that needs the date from the date picker. Please note there is no model associated with this view.

Comment: I have done something similar but using a signalR hub doing alot of the heavy lifting.

Comment: are you not using the datepicker input field inside a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is related to mvc the controller would have a method associated with the post that you would perform to get the data from the form back to the controller.  This uses javascript to post data to your `LessonIndex()` method.

```
<!--top of your page.-->
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf
@functions{
    public string GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()
    {
        return Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Context).RequestToken;
    }
}
```

```
<input type="date" id="lessonStart" name="lessonStart" />
<input type="Submit" id="PostButton" name="PostButton" Value="Go" />
```

```
@section Scripts{ // razor section at the bottom of mvc page 'cshtml'.
<script type="javascript">
 $(function(){   
   $("#PostButton").click(function(){
      var url = '@Url.Action("LessonIndex", "Lesson")';  //assuming controller is named Lesson
       var date= new Date(this.value).ToDateString();
      $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        type: "POST",
        data: "lessonStart=" + date,
        headers:{
        "RequestVerificationToken": '@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()'
        },
        success: function(response){
           console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(e){
          console.log(e.error);
        }
      });
   });
 }
</script>
}
```

this also assumes that the method looks like this

```
public class LessonController : Controller{

 [HttpPost]
 [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
 public IActionResult LessonIndex(DateTime lessonStart){
          var response = getLessons(lessonStart);
    return View(response.results);
 }

}
```

Comment: Hi, what does @inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf do? I've never seen that used before.  Is it needed?  Thank you

Comment: I tried out the code, and after I hit the "Go" button, I get this error: localhost:44304/LessonController/LessonIndex?lessonStart=Invalid%20Date

Comment: Right cause the route should be Lesson/LessonIndex?lessonStart="theDateSent" .  As for XSRF its cross site request forgery preventative measures, not really required but a good idea all things posted via javascript.  This is taken into account automatically if you where using `<form asp-antiforgery="true" />` but since the way you are doing this without a form which is fine, javascript has to be used.  If LessonController is actually showing up in the url, that route is designed wrong or is malformed.

Comment: Oh thank you, I didn't know you had to remove the 'controller' word.  thanks! It works now!

Answer (score 1):

" Note that the date is not used in a model, it just needs to be sent to a controller. "

You could use the ajax to pass the date as QueryString to the method in the controller.

Here is the test example

```
<input type="date" name="lessonsStart" id="lessonsStart">

@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#lessonsStart").change(function () {
        var inputDate = new Date(this.value).toDateString();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/ControllerName/lessonindex?startdate=" + inputDate,
            success: function () { }
        });
    });

</script>
}
```

The method in controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult LessonIndex(DateTime startDate)
    {

        return Json(startDate);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
    <h4>Remind me on</h4>
@(Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker()
        .Name("datetimepicker")
        .Value(DateTime.Now)
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%", title = "datetimepicker" })
        .DateInput()
)
</div>
```

Comment: Im sorry, but what is .Kendo()  ?  Thanks